# New Cypress test cases don't show up as available

Tags: json, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

For my custom test cases they no longer display as available in the UI: at the moment only the example cases are available.

- My test cases are inside the integrations folder.
- I have also tried to add a designated list of cases to cypress.json and cleared the program’s cache.

Even with all of that, my test cases will still not display. Anyone has any tips that might be of assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, guys so I figured it out. after trying to run scripts directly from the PowerShell terminal I noticed that my read/write permissions were not properly set up. I updated it. Opened cypress and everything was back in working order. I still cleared cypress' cache and ran the updater just in case (for safekeeping).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7.1 Microsoft has this very useful guide on how to change the execution policies